# MySQL: Selecting odd and even of the same field in a single statement

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql DB that stores user room access log with the following schema http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/553937

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `access_log` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `created` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `room_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `access_log` (`user_id`, `created`, `room_id`) VALUES
(1, '2019-08-05 01:56:40', 10),
(1, '2019-08-05 02:56:51', 11),
(1, '2019-08-05 03:32:49', 11),
(2, '2019-08-05 08:34:50', 12),
(3, '2019-08-05 08:36:51', 13),
(2, '2019-08-05 08:38:52', 10),
(2, '2019-08-05 10:46:02', 11),
(1, '2019-08-05 10:47:12', 12),
(3, '2019-08-05 11:06:27', 13),
(3, '2019-08-05 11:56:40', 10),
(3, '2019-08-05 12:56:51', 11),
(2, '2019-08-05 13:32:49', 11),
(2, '2019-08-05 18:34:50', 12),
(1, '2019-08-05 18:36:51', 13),
(2, '2019-08-05 18:38:52', 10),
(1, '2019-08-05 20:46:02', 11),

(3, '2019-08-06 01:34:50', 12),
(2, '2019-08-06 01:36:51', 13),
(1, '2019-08-06 01:38:52', 10),
(1, '2019-08-06 02:46:02', 11),
(2, '2019-08-06 08:47:12', 12),
(3, '2019-08-06 08:34:50', 12),
(3, '2019-08-06 08:36:51', 13),
(3, '2019-08-06 08:38:52', 10),
(3, '2019-08-06 10:46:02', 11),
(2, '2019-08-06 11:06:27', 13),
(3, '2019-08-06 11:56:40', 10),
(2, '2019-08-06 12:56:51', 11),

(2, '2019-08-07 01:34:50', 12),
(2, '2019-08-07 01:36:51', 13),
(2, '2019-08-07 01:38:52', 10),
(1, '2019-08-07 02:46:02', 11),
(2, '2019-08-07 08:47:12', 12),
(3, '2019-08-07 08:34:50', 12),
(3, '2019-08-07 08:36:51', 13),
(1, '2019-08-07 08:38:52', 10);
```

What I want is to select all "check-in"s and "check-out"s of each user, where check-in is every odd row and check-out is every even row of the user. The expected result should be:

```
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| user_id |      check_in       |      check_out      | 
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    1    | 2019-08-05 01:56:40 | 2019-08-05 02:56:51 |
|    1    | 2019-08-05 03:32:49 | 2019-08-05 10:47:12 |
|    1    | 2019-08-05 18:36:51 | 2019-08-05 20:46:02 |
|    2    | 2019-08-05 08:34:50 | 2019-08-05 08:38:52 |
|    2    | 2019-08-05 10:46:02 | 2019-08-05 13:32:49 |
|    2    | 2019-08-05 18:34:50 | 2019-08-05 18:38:52 |
|    3    | 2019-08-05 08:36:51 | 2019-08-05 11:06:27 |
|    3    | 2019-08-05 11:56:40 | 2019-08-05 12:56:51 |
|    1    | 2019-08-06 01:38:52 | 2019-08-06 02:46:02 |
|    2    | 2019-08-06 01:36:51 | 2019-08-06 08:47:12 |
|    2    | 2019-08-06 11:06:27 | 2019-08-06 12:56:51 |
|    3    | 2019-08-06 01:34:50 | 2019-08-06 08:34:50 |
|    3    | 2019-08-06 08:36:51 | 2019-08-06 08:38:52 |
|    3    | 2019-08-06 10:46:02 | 2019-08-06 11:56:40 |
|    1    | 2019-08-07 02:46:02 | 2019-08-07 08:38:52 |
|    2    | 2019-08-07 01:34:50 | 2019-08-07 01:36:51 |
|    2    | 2019-08-07 01:38:52 | 2019-08-07 08:47:12 |
|    3    | 2019-08-07 08:34:50 | 2019-08-07 08:36:51 |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add a column that says whether it's a check-in or check-out?

Comment: I can't change the schema of the table, it's used in other parts of the application.

Comment: Well, you should.

Comment: I can't see how adding a column which stored 'check in' and 'check out' would undermine other parts of the application.

Comment: Anyway, the general approach would be to use a user variable that alternates on each row, to split the table into odd and even rows. Then join those two subqueries to pair the check-in with check-out.

Comment: What I should do aside, I am limited to what I can. The schema I provided is a scaled down version of the original, but no matter what it is, there is no way I can change it because of various dependencies. This isn't out of the realms of reality, in fact it's very common when integrating various 3rd party systems that you have no access to. It's a little astonishing that developers today has no experience in that.

Comment: I have tried using 2 subqueries for each variable, it works well thanks.